# Cant leave page on backbutton after entering with queryParams Angular

Tags: angular, angular6, angular8, angular-routing, angular-router

im having trouble trying to leave the page whit pagination on a list.

```
original route => path: 'produtos/:categoria/:productId'
```

so when an enter the page i add this to init

```
  updatePage(pageIndex:number){
    this.currentPage = pageIndex;

    this._router.navigate([], {
      relativeTo: this.route,
      queryParams: {
        page: pageIndex
      },
     queryParamsHandling: 'merge',

    });

  }
```

And this code above works fine eg

- produtos/:categoria/:productId?page=1;
  produtos/:categoria/:productId?page=2;
  produtos/:categoria/:productId?page=3;

then i press backbutton

- rodutos/:categoria/:productId?page=3;
  produtos/:categoria/:productId?page=2;

i cant leave this page for some reason, keeps reloading at same page

- -produtos/:categoria/:productId?page=1;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When navigating to add query params, try adding `replaceUrl: true`. That should allow back button to work as if you hadn't created a new navigation event

https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationBehaviorOptions#replaceUrl

Answer (score 1):

well did by doing this logic here:

```
updatePage(pageIndex:number){
    this.currentPage = pageIndex;

    if (this.currentPage <= 1) {

      this._router.navigate([], {
       replaceUrl:true,
        queryParams: {
          page: pageIndex
        },
        queryParamsHandling: 'merge',

      });
      
    } else {
      this._router.navigate([], {
        relativeTo: this.route,
        queryParams: {
          page: pageIndex
        },
        queryParamsHandling: 'merge',

      });
    }
  }
```